# fire door between garage and residential living space!

Tags: garage, outdoor, exterior

[image]Can a solid door, under 1 3/4 inch thick, Designed-Equipped with a plexiglass-like panel, ever be accepted as a fire rated door between living space and a residential garage in California? I assume the Plexiglass disqualifies the fire rating!

Comment: Why  are you asking is there a problem?  We have door stuff in NH and it is best to ask the AHJ, thats a fact.

Comment: Myself the door may be ok.  If I was AHJ you would have to show me something on the plexiglass. Burn rate. If it was not good  make you change the glass  Seal the door with some type of stuff that increases fire rating.  And add sheet metal to the garage  side of the door.

Comment: Is the glazing panel in this door a standard sized light, or something non-standard in size?  Also, does it use a standard frame for mounting, or some oddball mounting scheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### While the non-rated glazing panel may or may not be OK here, I would shy away from it myself

While 2016 CalRC R302.5.1 (similar to 2015 IRC R302.5.1) does not require a *fire-rated* door for house-to-garage doors, it *does* require a solid wood or honeycomb-core steel door in such an application if a fire-rated door is not used and the house is not sprinklered:

> **R302.5.1 Opening protection**
>
> Openings from a private garage directly into a room used for sleeping purposes shall not be permitted. Other openings between the garage and residence shall be equipped with solid wood doors not less than 1 3/8 inches (35 mm) in thickness, solid or honeycomb-core steel doors not less than 1 3/8 inches (35 mm) thick, or 20-minute fire-rated doors, equipped with a self-closing and self-latching device.
>
> ***Exception:*** *Where the residence and the private garage are protected by an automatic residential fire sprinkler system in accordance with Sections R309.6 and R313, other door openings between the private garage and the residence need only be self-closing and self-latching. This exception shall not apply to rooms used for sleeping purposes.*

Given the situation, (a door that's otherwise OK, with factory fitted glazing), I would consult with your local AHJ about it, as it's a pretty...borderline call. Were I the AHJ, though, I would not permit non-rated glazing in a house-to-garage separation due to the rapid failure of ordinary glazing materials when exposed to fire.  The good news, though, is that if you know what to look for, fire rated doors are available with matching vision panels in this day and age.  And you don't have to settle for wired glass, either: a decent glazier should be able to hook you up with a fire-rated specialty tempered or specialty fire-rated/security laminated vision light in your door instead.